# Error: 'Id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'. Removal of id doesn't change anything

Tags: django, django-models

I used an id field in my django models.py file. Whenever I try to make migrations, I get the following error:
`SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
text_modifier.Posts: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'.`

I'm trying to insert
`id = models.PositiveIntegerField()`

I'm trying to add the models to postgres

I have tried removing the id field from the models.py file, but the error arises again (I have entirely no idea why). Also, I have tried setting the argument primary_key=True myself, this also didn't help. I understand now that id field is default in django, but the removal of it doesn't change anything.

I have another problem of django not being able to see the app I'm trying to put the id field in. I have copied the name of the app from the apps.py file and used
`set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=search_simple.settings`
to ensure it works properly. Can it be the issue?

My python:
Python 3.11.2

My django:
4.1.7

Existing model:

```
from django.db import models

#adds columns to the database in postgresql
class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    rubrics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

Desired output:
Columns: id, rubrics, created_date, text in postgres + created table

Comment: can you add existing model and output of that model you want?

Comment: Sure!Models + desired output in postgres added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField()  # remove it there's no need to add id here because it will automatically be created and auto-generated 
    rubrics = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

    def __str__(self):
       return f"{self.rubrics}"
```

`null=True` and `blank=True` are both used to specify options for fields in a model. It's worth noting that `blank=True` implies `null=True`. So, if you set `blank=True` , you don't need to set `null=True` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I keep getting the same error with id field and with removed id field.

Comment: can you please remove migrations and then migrate and remove db as well.
python manage.py flush

Comment: more months spent with django and I realised what you were telling me is actually right. you can also use id with primary_key=True, exactly what the error was about. so, albeit late, thanks!